# Java 2d array to generate grid - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1

Tags: java, 2d, android, algorithm, grid

I am creating a Hashi Puzzle game (Islands and Bridges) I am generating a 2d grid with Islands that can be connected using bridges, I am also running a DFS algorithm to check if the map is solvable I am getting this error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1

I am using a 2d array to generate the map,What could cause the error?

Land.java

```
public class Land {

    private int[][] BRIDGES_TO_BUILD;

    private boolean[][] IS_ISLAND;
    private Direction[][] BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT;

    public Land(int[][] bridgesToDo){
        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(bridgesToDo);

        int R = bridgesToDo.length;
        int C = bridgesToDo[0].length;
        BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[R][C];
        IS_ISLAND = new boolean[R][C];
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = null;
                IS_ISLAND[i][j] = bridgesToDo[i][j] > 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public Land(Land other){
        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(other.BRIDGES_TO_BUILD);
        int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
        int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;
        BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[R][C];
        IS_ISLAND = new boolean[R][C];
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = other.BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j];
                IS_ISLAND[i][j] = other.IS_ISLAND[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public int[] next(int r, int c, Direction dir){
        int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
        int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

        // out of bounds
        if(r < 0 || r >=R || c < 0 || c >= C)
            return null;


        // motion vectors
        int[][] motionVector = {{-1, 0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};
        int i = Arrays.asList(values()).indexOf(dir);

        // calculate next
        int[] out = new int[]{r + motionVector[i][0], c + motionVector[i][1]};

        r = out[0];
        c = out[1];

        // out of bounds
        if(r < 0 || r >=R || c < 0 || c >= C)
            return null;

        // return
        return out;
    }

    public int[] nextIsland(int r, int c, Direction dir){
        int[] tmp = next(r,c,dir);
        if(tmp == null)
            return null;
        while(!IS_ISLAND[tmp[0]][tmp[1]]){
            tmp = next(tmp[0], tmp[1], dir);
            if(tmp == null)
                return null;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public boolean canBuildBridge(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
        if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
            return canBuildBridge(r0, c1, r1, c0);
        }
        if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
            return canBuildBridge(r1, c0, r0, c1);
        }

            if (r0 == r1) {
                int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Direction.EAST);
                if (tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
                    return false;
                if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0)
                    return false;
                if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
                    return false;
                for (int i = c0; i <= c1; i++) {
                    if (IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                        continue;
                    if (BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] == Direction.NORTH)
                        return false;
                }
            }
        if(c0 == c1){
            int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Direction.SOUTH);
            if(tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
                return false;
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0 || BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
                return false;
            for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                    continue;
                if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] == EAST) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // default
        return true;
    }

    public int[] lowestTodo(){
        int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
        int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

        int[] out = {0, 0};
        for (int i=0;i<R;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] == 0)
                    continue;
                if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0)
                    out = new int[]{i, j};
                if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] < BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]])
                    out = new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }
        if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0) {
                return null;
        }
        return out;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    private int[][] copy(int[][] other){
        int[][] out = new int[other.length][other.length == 0 ? 0 : other[0].length];
        for(int r=0;r<other.length;r++)
            out[r] = Arrays.copyOf(other[r], other[r].length);
        return out;
    }

    public void connect(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
        if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
            connect(r0, c1, r1, c0);
            return;
        }
        if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
            connect(r1, c0, r0, c1);
            return;
        }
        if(!canBuildBridge(r0, c0, r1, c1))
            return;

        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0]--;
        BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1]--;

        if(r0 == r1){
            for (int i = c0; i <= c1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                    continue;
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] = Direction.EAST;
            }
        }
        if(c0 == c1){
            for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                    continue;
                BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] = Direction.NORTH;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Search function with Map Generation

```
 public int[][] debug_board_state_easy = new int[4][4];
 void search() {

        Map<Point, List<Direction>> remainingOptions = new HashMap<>();

        Stack<Land> gameTree = new Stack<>();
        gameTree.push(new Land(debug_board_state_easy));

        while (true) {

            Land state = gameTree.peek();
            int[] p = state.lowestTodo();
            if (p == null)
                System.out.println("solution found");

            // move to next game state
            int r = p[0];
            int c = p[1];
            System.out.println("expanding game state for node at (" + r + ", " + c + ")");

            List<Direction> ds;
            if (remainingOptions.containsKey(new Point(r, c)))
                ds = remainingOptions.get(new Point(r, c));
            else {
                ds = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
                    int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(r, c, dir);
                    if (tmp == null)
                        continue;
                    if (state.canBuildBridge(r, c, tmp[0], tmp[1]))
                        ds.add(dir);
                }
                remainingOptions.put(new Point(r, c), ds);
            }

            // if the node can no longer be expanded, and backtracking is not possible we quit
            if (ds.isEmpty() && gameTree.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("no valid configuration found");
                return;
            }

            // if the node can no longer be expanded, we need to backtrack
            if (ds.isEmpty()) {
                gameTree.pop();
                remainingOptions.remove(new Point(r, c));
                System.out.println("going back to previous decision");
                continue;
            }
            Log.e("gameTree", "WE ARE CRASHING HERE");
            Direction dir = ds.remove(0);
            System.out.println("connecting " + dir.name());
            remainingOptions.put(new Point(r, c), ds);
            Land nextState = new Land(state);
            int[] tmp = state.nextIsland(r, c, dir);
            nextState.connect(r, c, tmp[0], tmp[1]);
            gameTree.push(nextState);
        }
    }

  private void setCurrentState(State new_state) {
    this.current_state = new_state;
  }

  public State getCurrentState() {
    return current_state;
  }
}

    private void InitializeEasy() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        setCurrentState(new State(WIDTH_EASY));
        for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state_easy.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state_easy[row].length; column++) {
                debug_board_state_easy[row][column] = Integer.valueOf(rand.nextInt(5));

            }

        }


        for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state_easy.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state_easy[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(debug_board_state_easy[row][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        this.search();
        for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH_EASY; ++row) {
            for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH_EASY; ++column) {


                getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column] = new BoardElement();
                getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges = Integer.valueOf(debug_board_state_easy[row][column]);
                getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].row = row;
                getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].col = column;

                if (getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges > 0) {
                    getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].is_island = true;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure if you tried this yet, but maybe run a debugger, set a breakpoint at or near the failing line, look at the call stack, and trace through that way?

Comment: @Ken I have tried to debug this already, unfortunately it can't find the cause of this problem ;/

Comment: The problem appears to be that the index is -1. Which line specifically in the above code throws that exception? There's a ton of array accesses in the code snippet. If you can identify which line produces the exception you work backwards from there to determine how you ended up with an index of -1.

Comment: @JoshPetrie This line throws the exepction `// calculate next
        int[] out = new int[]{r + motionVector[i][0], c + motionVector[i][1]};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the line that throws the exception is

```
int[] out = new int[]{r + motionVector[i][0], c + motionVector[i][1]};
```

we can determine that `motionVector` is the array being indexed (it is the only index operation), and thus it is an array of length 4 that you are attempting to index with the value -1.

The only variable used to index `motionVector` is `i`, so `i` must be -1.

Just above, you have

```
int[][] motionVector = {{-1, 0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};
int i = Arrays.asList(values()).indexOf(dir);
```

`indexOf` returns -1 if the given object cannot be found in the list, so the root cause here is that you're not able to find `dir` in the list produced by `values()`.

This is likely because `dir` is not one of the four direction values you put into the list, or because the equality operation for `Direction` is wrong or will not compare equal when you expect (note [how `indexOf` performs its test](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))).

Comment: I was missing `Direction`] in `int i = Arrays.asList(Direction.values()).indexOf(dir);`